# Handle authentication redirection from Angular 2

Tags: angular, http, authentication, redirect, cas

We have an Angular 2 based web application and it retrieves data from secured REST-API.

Upon first REST-API request, it will return a URL with a redirect(302) response for initiating a GET request. Angular 2 does not automatically redirect to this URL and the request fails.
Note that the login to the REST-API was already done using a centralized authentication system and this redirection does not need to show a login page and get the input from the user. It only need to call the GET request.

How can we initiate a GET request to the provided redirection URL(which comes from the HTTP:302 response)  and retrieve data automatically?

If we go to the the REST-API call from the browser, it will automatically redirect to the given URL and returns the data.

Angular source for initiating REST-API call

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { Response, Headers, RequestOptionsArgs, URLSearchParams, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';

this.http.get(url, options)
             .subscribe(
               (response: Response) => {
                 // handle response
               },
               (error: any) => {
                 //handle error
               }
             );
```

Browser console error

[image]

Request and response
[image]

- Update

I figured out the solution as restriction happens due to cross-origin restriction. I solved it by accessing everything using the same hostname.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently facing this same problem, although for a different reason. I have multiple microservices and am using a router so the angular frontend only needs to know about that router. Now, when the angular frontend needs a specific microservice, I just callthe router which then returns a redirect to the correct microservice. The advantage of this is that the frontend only needs to know about the one microservice and I can freely add, remove, rename, etc. the other microservices.

This does mean that my router microservice returns 307 responses for almost everything. The way I'm implementing it on the angular side is to just test the response for this HTTP status code. If I get a 307, I know it's my router redirect. Then I can request the location header and resend my request to that location.

I should guess this would work exactly the same for you, just test your responses for redirect HTTP status codes. if you get one of the redirect codes, get the location from the response headers and resend the request to that location.